# Why should we use UTF-8 as the 'native2ascii' encoding option rather than ISO-8859-1?

Tags: java

When creating Properties class in Java, it requires the input stream must be encoded in [ISO 8859-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1). But in practice, I use UTF-8 to convert non-Latin properties files by the [`native2ascii`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/native2ascii.html) tool rather than ISO-8859-1.

- [According to the JDK documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html), the input stream should be encoded ISO-8859-1.
  That's to say, the source file is encoding in ISO-8859-1.
- According to it, decoding and encoding should use the same ISO-8859-1. Properties class in Java should decode using ISO-8859-1.
- According to testing, actually we use UTF-8 as the encoding
  option in native2ascii rather than ISO-8859-1. Why?

Test as follow:

- Create the *test.properties* file which contains: "key=Ü"
- Generated ISO-8859-1 property file: key=\u00c3\u009c

  ```
  native2ascii -encoding ISO-8859-1 test.properties iso88591.propertie:
  ```
- Generated UTF-8 property file:  key=\u00dc

  ```
  native2ascii -encoding UTF-8 test.properties utf8.properties
  ```
- Create Properties to load the two generated property files:

  ```
   Properties p = new Properties();
   //InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("src/test/java/com/active/translation/iso88591.properties");
   InputStream inStream = new FileInputStream("src/test/java/com/active/translation/utf8.properties");
   p.load(inStream);

   System.out.println(p.getProperty("key"));
  ```
- *iso88591.propertie* result is:  Ã
- *utf8.properties* result is: Ü

---

[Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15778018/why-utf-8-as-native2ascii-encoding-option-rather-than-iso-8859-1#comment22430361_15778018):

> That `-encoding` needs to match the actual encoding used in your source file. From the looks of it, that is UTF-8.

Comment: _"According to JDK doc,"_ which JDK documentation, specifically?

Comment: That `-encoding` needs to match the actual encoding used in your source file. From the looks of it, that is UTF-8.

Comment: In UNICODE that character is U+00DC. In UTF-8 encoding, it would be 0xC39C. When that file was read with ISO-8859-1 encoding, it read the UTF-8 encoded character as two ISO-8859-1 encoded characters: 0xC3 0x09c. As Thilo suggested, make the --encoding parameter match the actual encoding of the file.

Comment: JDK doc: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Properties.html. " except the input/output stream is encoded in ISO 8859-1 character encoding"

Comment: As Thilo suggested, the -encoding option is what the actual encoding of source file. When saving test.properties with "ISO-8859-1" encoding, then iso88591.propertie: key=\u00dc and value via getProperty("key") is correct.
'native2ascii -encoding ISO-8859-1 test.properties iso88591.propertie'

Comment: I don't know native2ascii uses which unicode implementation. But it does not matter, the unicode implementation is compatible with ISO-8859-1. Then Properties class can decode properly with ISO-8859-1.

Comment: The misspelling `iso88591.propertie` confuses matters (though at least it is consistently used).